# Regular expressions allow any alphanumeric characters, any letters with accents and bullets, dashes and underscore

Tags: regex, expression, preg-match

I'm doing a regular expression where you can allow any characters:

**1.** Any alphanumeric character upper case and lower case, including ñ

**2.** Any letter upper case and lower case, with an accent "áéíóú"

**3.** Any letter upper case and lower case bulleted "äëïöü"

**4.** Underscore

**5.** Dashes

**6.** Points

**7.** Semicolon

**8.** Newlines

**9.** Remove any special characters example: ¡?=)(/&%$#"!|°¬´+}{}.,;:_[]¨*` etc...

**10.** And specify a minimum and maximum number of characters, eg between 0 and 75

I searched a lot of information and I found a number of functions, but to achieve this I have to combine a lot of code, I would like to do this in a regular expression.

**I'm doing my own role, until now I have a feature that allows any alphanumeric characters, spaces, dashes and dots, for example:**

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\. ]{0,75}+$/
```

**I found this feature to remove special characters:**

```
function remove_characters_special($text = '') {    
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d\.]+~u', ' ', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

**It is valid to do this for accented letters and bullets?**

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\. áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑäëïÖüÄËÏÖü]{0,75}+$/
```

How can I complete this function?

Comment: Also your match pattern need to be unicode regex: `^[\pL\pN\s._-]{0,75}$/u` add `u` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) and use [unicode categories](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) if input is utf-8.

Comment: @ bobble bubble -  Thank you very much, I've been testing and it seems that for the script fails, but I changed the pattern /^[\pL\pN\pZ._\-]{0,75}$/., and if it works but if I add letters with accents or bullets fails, you need to escape the script in the pattern.

Comment: Oh! Had a slip. Did you try `$pattern = '/^[\pL\pN\s._-]{0,75}$/u';` lacked starting delimiter.

Comment: @ Bubble bobble - works perfectly, it was not necessary to escape the script, just a detail, when the string this colo $Ñ, gives the following error: Notice: Undefined variable: Ñ

Comment: Also, if I add a text a semicolon ; or two points : shows a error.

Comment: Can you demonstrate [error in eval.in](https://eval.in/526922) or paste code in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)? It seems to be another problem.

Comment: You can see here: http://goo.gl/K67U7A When you run the code displays the error. The error is not in your code, this very well, the error is of special characters : ;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104787/discussion-between-learning-and-sharing-and-bobble-bubble).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ bobble bubble, after a long conversation I could get the regular expression I needed, I will share them for who can serve, if they need to filter all data before it is inserted into the database, even you accept commas, semicolons and double point, and thereafter you may be adding more special characters allowed.

```
$text = "áéíóú ÁÉÍÓÚ äëïöüÄËÏÖÜ - _ , : ; ";
$pattern = '/^[,:;\pL\pN\s._-]{0,75}$/u';

if (!preg_match($pattern, $text)) {
    echo "No valid";
}   else {
    echo "valid";
}
```

**Other examples:** These codes are mine examples, if there is a PHP GURU who has an easier way, it would be helpful to show it.

**1. Without specifying numbers of characters.**

```
$pattern = '/^[,:;\pL\pN\s._-]+$/u';
```

**2. Allow double and single quotation marks and brackets without specifying numbers of characters.**

```
$pattern = '/^[\'\'\"\"\(\),:;\pL\pN\s._-]+$/u';
```

@ bobble bubble Thank you so much, I love you :)